# MongoDB : Failed to load js file

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a bash script , from which i run js file which is responsible to update the table with a new filed if it doesn't exists .

But while executing bash script , i am getting the following error .

```
Wed Jul  3 00:05:18 Error: error doing update (anon):1552
failed to load: logincount.js
```

This is a simple js file which will update a field called as yesterday  inside userCollection table

```
 var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate()-1;
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var yesterday = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
    db.userCollection.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {$set: {yesterday : yesterday}},false,true)
```

Please let me know if there is any wrong the above js file and what is the reason for this error ??

please advice , thanks in advance

One more thing i have forgot to update if i remove the last line , the below line

```
db.userCollection.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {$set: {yesterday : yesterday}},false,true)
```

it doesn't complain anything . i guess that if the filed yesterday  should be global or what ?? if yes then how can i make that field global ??

Comment: How are you loading the file? Can you show us the code you use in bash to actually load the file?

Comment: my script file consists of only this line mongo $TECH_MONG_LOC/at logincount.js

Comment: tangentially, it might be cleaner to get yesterday like this: `var d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); var yesterday = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate()` -- your method will return `2013-8-0` on August 1st.

Answer (score 1):

The variable db is not defined. Take a look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

You can do this:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDatabase");
```

or this:

```
db = connect("localhost:27020/myDatabase");
```